# Find Symbol Sizes in a Binary

Tags: gdb, elf, disassembly, debug-symbols, objdump

I used `objdump -t` on the debug-info file of a program to find the address ranges of each function. There are a few functions the bounds of which can not be determined using this method. Because `objdump` reports `0` for their sizes. These symbols are shown, below:

```
deregister_tm_clones 0000000000197ce0
register_tm_clones 0000000000197d20
__do_global_dtors_aux 0000000000197d70
frame_dummy 0000000000197db0
_fini 00000000004e9474
_init 00000000001889e8
```

How can I determine their sizes? I can only imagine using `GDB` `disas` command on the start address and find the end of the disassembly for the function. This may not work in all cases. What is the *standard* approach?

---

**UPDATE:**

I am implementing a `Pintool` to generate callstacks at runtime. I only need symbols in certain binaries. In other words, I need a subset of functions (e.g., those in the `GTK` library) to be included in the callstack. Therefore, at runtime, I will need the ranges for these libraries.

On the other hand, I need the ranges for the symbols to find their **outgoing** jumps. This is a sign of **tail-call elimination**, which **necessitates** stack updates.

Comment: "What is the standard approach?" -- there isn't one. Why do you care about the sizes of these symbols?

Comment: I am writing a `Pintool` that generates the backtrace for a subset of the binaries in the runtime stack. These are some of those that should be included in the generated stack.

Comment: "generates the backtrace for a subset of the binaries in the runtime stack" -- I think you mean "for a subset of functions" (or else I have no idea what you said). I still don't get what symbol sizes have to do with backtrace. Please edit your question with a more detailed explanation of _why_ you need symbol sizes at all, and why you need symbol sizes for these particular symbols.